# ROW_NUMBER odd behaviour in combination with union

Tags: row-number

I need a row_number in my view. I get some unexpected results

This query works great

```
SELECT chart.*
     , dist.FunctionCode
     , dist.FunctionDescription
  FROM [dbo].[vw_OrganizationChart] chart
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT OE_code, FunctionCode, FunctionDescription FROM  FormationDistribution
             UNION 
             SELECT DISTINCT OE_code, Function_Code, Function_Description FROM dbo.FormationBudget
) dist
    ON chart.OE_Code = dist.OE_code
```

My first column look like

xxx
xxx
xxx

But if i add

```
SELECT *
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Layer_code0_Description) 
FROM (
```

to the query all my data gets messed up.

Now the result of the 1st column is

1 aaa
2 xxx
3 zzz

So somehow by wanting to add a sequence nummber the result of the query is changed

If i remove the union (so only use 1 table)
OR
if i create a table of the union
OR
if i create a table of the inline view

Then my results are as expected.

1 xxx
2 xxx
3 xxx

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Without seeing your actual data I can't post a formal answer.  However, what is likely happening here is just the result of your query not using a proper `ORDER BY` clause to order the results.  As a result, SQL is free to return any order it wants.  It's curious that adding a call to `ROW_NUMBER` changes the order, but actually makes sense, given that the query plan my change by the addition of `ROW_NUMBER` (and therefore the natural "order" of the query result set).

Comment: No i want to add a sequence number to a view

The problem isnt that my data is reordered but the problem is that the result of the query is different

My original query returns

xxx 111 bbb
xxx 222 aaa
xxx 333 ccc

After adding the sequence number i get

bbb 444 qqq
xxx 222 aaa

It seems like in some cases data is shifted to the left and in some cases not

If there is a GURU i can demonstrate it in Teams